# redefine \author

Tags: titles

Could you help me please
I want to redefine \author in  the way that the name is in small capitale  and the first name in roman

`\newcommand{\np}[2]{\textrm{#1}\textsc{#2}}`

How can I put it to `\def\@author`that affect all  document's style

sorry for my bad english

Comment: So you're using it in our document as `\np{First}{Last}`?

Comment: yes, in french we use the name family in small capitale in second position

Comment: Why not `\author{\np{First}{Last}}`?

Comment: just imagine if I have few documents?

Comment: Imean a lot of, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the paper has just one author and you use only the name, without affiliation and other info, you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\@breakauthor#1\@breakauthor}
\def\@breakauthor#1 #2\@breakauthor{%
  \gdef\@author{#1 \textsc{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{Adam Uthor}
\title{A nice paper}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, adding the code to every paper of yours is heavier than adding `\textsc{...}` around the family name.